# call a javascript function inside ajax success function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I Have an ajax success function that I wich to call inside it another javascript function, but i don't know the command or the JQuery function to do that.

Here is my function:

```
  function save(id_matiere,id_grp,id_niv)
       { 
           $.ajax({
          url : "<?php echo site_url('index.php/programme/ajouter_ens_mat')?>",
          type: "POST",
          data: $('#form').serialize()+ '&m='+ id_matiere+ '&g='+ id_grp,
          dataType: "JSON",
          success: function(data)
          {
            afficher(id_grp,id_niv);
          }
        });
       }
```

The function name that I wich to call is called "afficher".

Tell me please how to do this.
thank you!

Comment: Why would you need jQuery to call a JavaScript function?

Comment: Pretty much like your code. Have you tried it? What happened?

Comment: That looks ok but you probably want to get `id_grp` and `id_niv` from the returned data.

Comment: The code looks about right. When success, it will trigger your function.

Comment: every thing is fine, I tested the success function with an alert! so instead of the alert, I want to call another function

Comment: I called this function with the function that I want to recall in my success, so it is much like a back process

Comment: I tried my code and nothing happened ! The command is wrong as I concluded

Comment: Your conclusion is wrong. The code you've provide is already correct. You call a function from within a function exactly like you call it outside a function, there is no difference.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The context in Ajax success callback handler will not be same as the function invoking the Ajax. You will have to maintain a reference to the context so you can access it inside the callback.

In this case, I've stored the reference in me variable so it can be used inside success callback handler.

```
     function save(id_matiere,id_grp,id_niv)
     { 
      // I'm assuming save is called by another JS function
      var me = this;

       $.ajax({
      url : "<?php echo site_url('index.php/programme/ajouter_ens_mat')?>",
      type: "POST",
      data: $('#form').serialize()+ '&m='+ id_matiere+ '&g='+ id_grp,
      dataType: "JSON",
      success: function(data)
      {
        me. afficher(id_grp,id_niv);
      }
    });
   }
```

Comment: Yes it is called by another JS function with is "afficher" and I want to get back to it in my success, and i've tried this and hasn't work

Comment: can you post the caller function code as well.

Comment: Sorry, your code works, I just forgot to put this "echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));" in my controller function to tell the ajax that my resuest is fullfilled! I was adding this code before I changed some of my code, that why my alert worked before! Thank you